# Effect of redirects on reboot command

Tags: linux, redirect, reboot, busybox, openwrt

I'm running linux on a mips based system (specifically openwrt on a router).

When I run the reboot (as supplied by busybox) i.e. just `reboot` on it's own, the system reboots, but some of the services (webserver, dhcp/dns, dsl stuff) don't start up.

However when I reboot via the web interface, all the services start normally. I looked at the code and saw that the web interface runs `reboot > /dev/null 2>&1`. Running this command also reboots and starts up0 the services properly.

My question is how does redirecting stdout and stderr to /dev/null affect the startup of services upon the next boot?

Also, I'm wondering, would reboot contain architecture specific code?

Comment: I've got no idea about your main question, but regarding your "also:" the *userspace program* [`reboot(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/reboot) just makes a root-only system call, [`reboot(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/reboot); there's nothing architecture-specific about it (nor is it Linux-specific in *concept*; there's been a system call with that name all the way back to V7, if memory serves, although details vary). The *process of rebooting* definitely does involve architecture-specific code but it's all in the kernel and/or the firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, redirecting stdout/stderr must not be able to affect the boot process (and where would that be saved anyway?). There must be something else causing this.

Does "shutdown -r now" work?

Comment: Unfortunately shutdown does not exist on system nor does it look like it is part of busybox. However thanks to Zack, who pointed me to the reboot man.8 page, it says that reboot run shutdown when run with no options. Also it syscalls reboot() when `reboot -f` is run. This properly reboots the system. [break] I probably misphrased my question, I don't mean the redirects directly affect the process. I get the feeling the redirections help "deamonize" the reboot process. (Redirecting std streams to /dev/null are part of daemonization.) I tested this out by running `reboot &` which works properly.

Comment: Maybe the following happened: you trigger a reboot, so the system starts stopping services. However, that kills your program/script, which in turn also kills the pending reboot command. Then essentially you didn't complete the reboot, and end up with a "partially shut down" system.
Detaching the reboot command is definitely a good idea. The killall command should have an exception built in for shutdown.

Comment: That must be it. It never occurred to me that the reboot() syscall might not have been called by the reboot command. Looking at the reboot source code, it tries to kill all processes before running reboot. Hence killing the parent shell process might cause child reboot process to prematurely end. I was hoping to test this out using the uptime command to see if `reboot` actually did reboot. But for some magical reason `reboot` on it's own is now working.